# I need to improve DB query time

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL database to query one of the huge tables and it's taking too long 5-6 seconds and sometimes 10-20 seconds.

```
SELECT theminutes.theminute, IFNULL(summary.`costweek`,0) total_cost,IFNULL(summary.`timeweek`,0) total_time
                FROM (
                     SELECT DATE(NOW())-INTERVAL seq.seq DAY theminute   
                       FROM (
                                SELECT 0 AS seq 
                                  UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2 
                                  UNION ALL SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4
                                  UNION ALL SELECT 5  UNION ALL SELECT 6
                             ) seq 
                       ) theminutes
                LEFT JOIN (
                     SELECT DATE(cdr.starttime) theminute,
                            COALESCE(SUM(`sessionbill`),0) `costweek`,
                            COALESCE(SUM(`sessiontime`),0) `timeweek`
                       FROM cc_call cdr
                       WHERE (DATE(cdr.starttime) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND cdr.accountcode = {$user_id} AND cdr.direction = 'outbound'
                      GROUP BY DATE(cdr.starttime)
                    ) summary USING (theminute)
                ORDER BY theminutes.theminute
```

When I ran "EXPLAIN" on this query I got this:

[image: explain query output]

Live table contains approx 10 million rows. Please guide me if I can improve my query or if I need to optimize my table.

Edit:

Output of

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE cc_calls
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like this is an index issue. Do you have index on `starttime`, `accountcode`, and `direction` column on `cc_call` table? Could you update your question with the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE  cc_call`? And what `CDR_QUERY_IDX3` index contains?

Comment: Added output of SHOW CREATE TABLE

Comment: You have indexed `starttime` column, but you access this column with `DATE` function, that will ignore index. Could you use your column data only when performing `WHERE` clause? Try change:
`WHERE (DATE(cdr.starttime) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND cdr.accountcode = {$user_id} AND cdr.direction = 'outbound'` into this:
`WHERE cdr.starttime >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 DAY AND cdr.accountcode = {$user_id} AND cdr.direction = 'outbound'`

Comment: Depending on your hardware 5 to 20 seconds for a query containing left join, group by and order by instructions plus function calls over 10 million records might be a good value. Do you have any tool showing the query execution plan? This may help to find out which indexes are used or if it makes sense to add other indexes. If possible, try to avoid the function calls since they might ignore the indexes.

Comment: let's normalize your database first and then have another look

Comment: @Hermanto, It seems that when I change the conditional part to this: `WHERE cdr.starttime >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 DAY)` it takes less than a sec. Let me do more research, by the way, thank you for highlighting this :)

Comment: You're welcome. Nice to hear that. :)